# concatenate 3 pandas dataframes on index and one column

Tags: pandas

I'd like to concatenate 3 dataframes on index **and** on 'type' column where some index values are missing (dfb and dfc have incomplete index, while dfa has complete index) . when I do concat some columns disappear as shown below. (i'd like final dataframe have MultiIndex so I can pick up parts of concatenated dataframe by type, and df['type2'] should have sorted index).

I tried concat with various parameters but it did not work.

```
dfa=pd.DataFrame({'type':['type1','type1','type2'],'a':[10,20,30]},index=[1,2,3])
dfb=pd.DataFrame({'type':['type1','type2'],'b':[11,21]},index=[2,3])
dfc=pd.DataFrame({'type':['type3'],'c':[33]},index=[3])
dfa
dfb
dfc

pd.concat([dfa,dfb,dfc],axis=0,keys=['type']) #wrong. columns b and c disappear!
```

[image]
I'd like the efficient solution as I have 5 dataframes whith 2000 "types" and index size of each is around 10K

desired:
[image]

example of desired  dataframe:

```
   pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,20,30,np.nan],'b':[np.nan,11,21,np.nan],'c': 
   [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,33],'type':['type1','type1','type2','type3']},index= 
   [1,2,3,3])
```

Comment: Can you provide example of your desired result?

Comment: added desired dataframe.

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating df:

```
dfa=pd.DataFrame({'type':['type1','type1','type2'],'a':[10,20,30]},index=[1,2,3])
dfb=pd.DataFrame({'type':['type1','type2'],'b':[11,21]},index=[2,3])
dfc=pd.DataFrame({'type':['type3'],'c':[33]},index=[3])
```

You can use `merge` and `reset_index` like this:

```
dfs = [dfa, dfb, dfc] # ... add as many df as you wish

res = dfs[0].reset_index()
for i in range(1,len(dfs)):
    res = res.merge(dfs[i].reset_index(), how='outer', left_on=['index','type'], right_on=['index','type'])
res = res.set_index('index')
print(res)
```

The result will be:

```
        type     a     b     c
index                         
1      type1  10.0   NaN   NaN
2      type1  20.0  11.0   NaN
3      type2  30.0  21.0   NaN
3      type3   NaN   NaN  33.0
```

Comment: what if i have 5 dataframes

Comment: @alexprice I've modified my answer to make it more suitable for different number of dataframes

Answer (score 1):

The problems that you aren't defining enough keys to match the number of dataframes concatenated.

Try this:

```
pd.concat([dfa, dfb, dfc], axis=0, keys=['type_a', 'type_b', 'type_c'])
```

Output:

```
             a     b     c   type
type_a 1  10.0   NaN   NaN  type1
       2  20.0   NaN   NaN  type1
       3  30.0   NaN   NaN  type2
type_b 2   NaN  11.0   NaN  type1
       3   NaN  21.0   NaN  type2
type_c 3   NaN   NaN  33.0  type3
```

Or leave `keys` parameter out all together:

```
pd.concat([dfa, dfb, dfc], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
      a     b     c   type
1  10.0   NaN   NaN  type1
2  20.0   NaN   NaN  type1
3  30.0   NaN   NaN  type2
2   NaN  11.0   NaN  type1
3   NaN  21.0   NaN  type2
3   NaN   NaN  33.0  type3
```

Comment: please check latest edit how desired dataframe shoud look like (more or less). in your latets output should be only 4 rows as row #1 and #4 should be combined together (because same type1), for example.